# What does it mean when compiler can't find include-files, but the IDE does...?

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, indexer

I'm using Eclipse CDT Kepler and I often got these errors, where the program isn't able to build because of a missing reference - often this is even a std. library like `/usr/include/linux/limits.h` - but Eclipse does, since [CTRL+Left Mouse Click on the "missing" variable/function/...] leads to the right .h file.

I added the same path and include file for gcc g++ and the linker. But the problem still isn't solved.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: It means the search paths for both are different

Comment: Is it really that the compiler can't find the header file or do you have undefined references?

Comment: @PlasmaHH true - but how to make them the same...

Comment: @jasal isn't it the same? the error is: `Error: >>PATH_MAX<< is not declared (first use in this function)` (PATH_MAX is a `#define` in limits.h) oh I forgot afterwards another error appears in the list `Symbol 'PATH_MAX' could not be resolved`

Comment: @user3085931 No, undefined references occur at the linker stage when it can't find the actual implementation. What you observe are missing declarations.

Comment: yes you're right, it was a typo here in the comment.

Comment: How have you added the include path for gcc? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298550/eclipse-c-including-header-file-from-my-source-folder

Comment: Well I also tried with absolute paths, but the error never changed.